# Is this php select statement secure?

Tags: php, select, bindparam

I'm parsing a url and using the number as an id to pull out the specific entry

So with a statement such as:

```
$blog_id = 5;

$query = "SELECT id,entry,date,views,comments,likes FROM blogs WHERE id=$blog_id ORDER by Id DESC";
```

Is that secure or should I use ....`id=?`... and use a bind_param ?

Comment: completely secure, as you aren't even running the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually: This code is secure. Why? It doesn't take any user input. So there is nothing to modify.

While this doesn't make sense, there is no way to perform an SQL Injection here. Once you are using POST, GET or Cookies, you HAVE TO validate the incoming information. You can do this by using `PDO::bind_param`, `filter_var()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: I think I understand what Tobi said, the $blog_id comes from parsing the URL, so if the URL is purposely setup to be harmful, then the statement would just pull it in anyway right? So the bind parameter part, I guess I will have to create filters to "secure" the query

Comment: If you get that from parsing the URL, you have to validate, yes. If you don't, you should lose the right to program and locked away in jail for 30 years.

Comment: haha yes, I am reading up more on what exactly bind_param does, seems to perform some sort of filter unless I Have to create the filters myself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statement for your sql, because you insert some values from an url, which can be manipulated and destroy your database

Comment: Just as a follow up question, how does the binding make it secure? I'm supposed to validate the input right? Like no symbols, only digits in this case? htmlcharescape and such?

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows that you are not getting the value from a URL but are hardcoding the value 5 into the variable with

```
$blog_id = 5;
```

If instead you have something like this

```
$blog_id = $_GET['blogid'];
```

then your code is insecure and open to MySQL injection. In that case you should use prepared statements which can include ? and bindParam. You can either use mysqli or PDO to do this. I prefer PDO.

Answer (score 1):

That seems vulnerable to SQL Injection. You have to check that $id only contains characters that are valid for your ids, and that is doesn't have semicolons or SQL Keywords

Comment: $blog_id from above, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Can't I filter the parsed URL to only have numbers? Can you cause damage with just numbers?

Comment: Oh that is how you meant it, it shouldn't be possible to do harm with numbers, maybe a check for the length of the numbers only string would make sense, but shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable $blog_id can't be changed (as shown in your question), you could say that this is safe. Yet it is recommended to always use prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

More info can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: right but it is pulled from the URL so not safe; this was a good refresher, I thank everyone for answering.